# cms.root Setting

Tags: civicrm.settings

When i set up the Settings this way:
http://example.com/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

```
[cms.root]/libraries/civicrm
```

It tries to resolve resources from:

```
http://default/...
```

When i change to absolute path:

```
http://example.com/libraries/civicrm
```

it works.
But should't the example above be correct?

**SOLVED Edit:**

as @Demerit and @Aidan corectly pointed out, that setting was in

```
civicrm.settings.php
```

in

```
web/sites/default/
```

TY!

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  On the Resource URL's settings page, click the help icon and check the values displayed there.  Check your civicrm.settings.php and see what URL's are set there.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, as the URLs don't look like Wordpress, but I had a similar problem when I had a dev version on dev.example.com. The absolute path is

> https://dev.example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

But [civicrm.root] is

> https://dev.example.com/dev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

The problem is that the files are held in subdirectory dev but this is handled by a redirect in the CMS hosting service.

There was no problem when the URL was just example.com. So also depends on the actual URL you use for CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd agree with @Aidan it's probably in civicrm.settings.php. Based on your other question you've used composer to install, and then likely used drush to enable the civicrm module. If you do that you need sometimes to pass the -l parameter to drush otherwise it puts "default" in for the domain name in civicrm.settings.php.